# Автофокус Texteare

Tags: javascript, html, html5, события

Всем привет. При установке курсора между двумя буквами в области `textarea` и последующем клике на элемент div добавляется буква между уже введенными ранее символами в `textarea`. Но при следующем клике на элемент div теряется ранее установленный фокус между элементами в `textarea` и символ добавляется в конец. Пробовал в `textarea` установить атрибут `autofocus`, но не помогло.

```js
function handleClick(event){
    const action = event.target.dataset.action //Получаю keyCode   
    area.value=area.value.substring(0, area.selectionStart) + String.fromCharCode(action) + area.value.substring(area.selectionEnd, area.value.length);
}
    
let keys = document.getElementsByClassName("key");
  [...keys].forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
)
```

```html
<textarea name="screen" id="area" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Введите данные с клавиатуры" autofocus></textarea>

<div class="keyboard">
            <div class='line'>
                <div class="key" data-action="192">À</div> <!--data-action это keyCode на клавиатуре --> 
                <div class="key" data-action="49">1</div>
                <div class="key" data-action="50">2</div>
                <div class="key" data-action="51">3</div>
                <div class="key" data-action="52">4</div>
              </div>
 </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
let keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key')
keys.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', handleClick));

function handleClick(event) {
  let oldSelectionStart = area.selectionStart;
  area.value = 
    area.value.substring(0, area.selectionStart) + 
    this.dataset.action +
    area.value.substring(area.selectionEnd, area.value.length);
  area.selectionStart = oldSelectionStart + 1;
  area.selectionEnd = oldSelectionStart + 1;
}
```

```css
.key {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="screen" id="area" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Введите данные с клавиатуры" autofocus></textarea>
<br/>
<div class="key" data-action="A">A</div>
<div class="key" data-action="B">B</div>
<div class="key" data-action="C">C</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Игорь, я пытаюсь разобраться в вашем решении и хотел бы уточнить. Я правильно понял, что в переменную oldSelectionStart мы кладем старый индекс входящего символа и при клике на эл-т div между строками изначальный символ сдвигается(т.е порядковый номер принимает новое значение) И в строках порядковое значение у всех эл-ов в строке сдвигается:
area.selectionStart = oldSelectionStart + 1,
 area.selectionEnd = oldSelectionStart + 1;
Правильно ли я понял?

Comment: @AzetX Да, правильно.

Comment: Понял, благодарю.